# Observable switch from one of many observables

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have a graph structure where each `Node<TData>` has a property `children: Observable<Node<TData>[]>`.

I'm working on a navigator for the graph that should have a `currentNode : Node<TData>` property and a single observable property: `navigable: Observable<Node<TData>[]>` which should emit the `children` of `currentNode` after its instance has changed.

Right now I'm assigning a new instance of the observable to the navigators `navigable` property whenever `currentNode` changes, which of course means that any subscriber needs to re-subscribe. How could I updated `navigable` without creating a new observable?

```
export class Navigator<TData>{

    private _navigable: Observable<Node<TData>[]> = of(<Node<TData>[]>[]);

    public get navigable(): Observable<Node<TData>[]> {
        return this._navigable;
    }

    private _currentNode: Node<TData> | undefined;

    public get currentNode(): Node<TData> | undefined {
        return this._currentNode;
    }

    public set currentNode(value: Node<TData>) {
        this._currentNode = value;
        this._navigable = this.currentNode.children;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. For this you need a `BehaviorSubject`.

```js
export class Navigator<TData>{
    private _navigable = new BehaviorSubject<Node<TData>[]>([]);

    public get navigable(): Observable<Node<TData>[]> {
        return this._navigable.asObservable();
    }

    private _currentNode: Node<TData> | undefined;

    public get currentNode(): Node<TData> | undefined {
        return this._currentNode;
    }

    public set currentNode(value: Node<TData>) {
        this._currentNode = value;
        this._navigable.next(this.currentNode.children);
    }
}
```

A `BehaviorSubject` will let you have a starting value (the equivalent of your `of(<Node<TData>[]>[])`) and you'll be able to push values into it (using `next`). Every time you do that, all the subscribers will receive the new value.

All of this could also be simplified as:

```js
export class Navigator<TData> {
  private _currentNode$$ = new BehaviorSubject<Node<TData> | undefined>(undefined);

  public get navigable(): Observable<Node<TData>[]> {
    return this._currentNode$$.pipe(map((node) => node?.children ?? []));
  }

  public get currentNode(): Node<TData> | undefined {
    return this._currentNode$$.value;
  }

  public set currentNode(value: Node<TData>) {
    this._currentNode$$.next(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `BehaviorSubject<T>` expect `T` when calling `next`? In my case, `Node<T>.children` is an observable of type `Node<T>[ ]`.

Comment: Are you refering to the first or second example I gave? It does expect `T` when using `next` indeed but what I've done looks alright

Comment: Actually both but your examples where still very helpful, I took your second example and just changed `map` to `switchmap` and now it seems to work as I had hoped.

Answer (score 0):

@maxime1992 answer was very helpful, this is what I ended up with:

```
export class Node<TData> {
  //omitted some code for initialization
  public children : Observable<Node<TData>[]>
}

export class Navigator<TData> {

  private _roots: Observable<Node<TData>[]> = of(<Node<TData>[]>[]) //init as empty

  public get roots(){
     return this._roots;
  }

  public set roots(value){
     this._roots = value;
     this._currentNode$$.next(undefined); //reset current node
  }

  private _currentNode$$ = new BehaviorSubject<Node<TData> | undefined>(undefined);

  public get navigable(): Observable<Node<TData>[]> {
    return this
       ._currentNode$$
       .pipe(switchMap((node) => node?.children ?? this.roots));
  }

  public SelectNode(node : Node<TData>){
    this._currentNode$$.next(node);
  }
}
```